# How to connect the connect () function in google-maps-react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-react

I'm trying to using google-maps-react with redux.
The problem is that redux doesn't refresh the state right away after actions.
Everything works only after I drag the map.

This is my code wrapper:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionToProps)(
GoogleApiWrapper({
        apiKey: ('some_api')
      })(MapContainer)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

As menitoned [here](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/pull/172), you have to redux compose to get it to work like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    lang: selectLang(state),
})

const enhance = compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    GoogleApiWrapper(({ lang }) => ({
        apiKey: 'API_KEY',
        language: lang,
    })),
)

export default enhance(MapContainer)
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding.